# get width if element using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello friends i want to get width of image which is wrapped in `<li>` following is my code

**SCRIPT**

```
var imageWidth = $('.slider_cont ul li').children('img').width();
console.log(imageWidth);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider_cont">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
            <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
            <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
            <li><img src="images/4.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My code give exact value when i open it in firefox but is gives 0(ZERO) when i check it into chrome .... I dont know why.. please help me guys

Comment: You can ask for an image's size after it has been loaded by the browser. Unless, in this case, you provide a `width` attribute in your `<img>`

Comment: @Alexander thanks for help brother.. actually i dont want to give width into `img` tag ... and given code is working in firefox not in chrome...

Comment: Try wrapping it in a `$(window).load(function(){ ... });`? (The problem with snippet is that you can't see code in context)

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 images in your list. Your code only logs the first one.

This saves the widths of the images in an array.

```
var imageWidth = new Array();
$('.slider_cont ul li').children('img').each(function() {
    imageWidth.push($(this).width());
});
console.log(imageWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome renders image differently with what FF does. To correctly get image width, you need to wait browser finish load image tag. One approach is to have onload event on image tag like below :

```
<script>
    function showWidth(){
        var imageWidth = $('.slider_cont ul li').children('img').width();
        console.log(imageWidth);
    }

</script>
<body>
    <div class="slider_cont">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="3Qp6h.png" alt=" " onload="showWidth()"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
var image = $('.slider_cont ul li').children('img');
console.log(image.clientWidth);
```